# Javascript dom element being parsed as string

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am having an issue using JavaScript with rails. I am using `getScrip`t to load the js in a file called `list.js.erb`, in which is:

```
var info = '<%= j(items_collection(@order, @items_list)) %>'
$('#items-list').html(info);
```

In inspect element, I can see that the response that I am actually getting is

```
var info = '&lt;div class=\&quot;control-group check_boxes optional 
order_items\&quot; id=\&quot;items-list\&quot;&gt;&lt;label class=\&quot;
check_boxes optional control-label\&quot;&gt;Items&lt;\/label&gt;&lt;div
class=\&quot;controls\&quot;&gt;&lt;label class=\&quot;checkbox\&quot;&gt;
&lt;input class=\&quot;check_boxes optional\&quot; id=\&quot;order_items_6\&quot;
name=\&quot;order[items][]\&quot; type=\&quot;checkbox\&quot; 
value=\&quot;6\&quot; /&gt;Chicken Burrito&lt;\/label&gt;&lt;
label class=\&quot;checkbox\&quot;&gt;&lt;input class=\&quot;
check_boxes optional\&quot; id=\&quot;order_items_7\&quot; 
name=\&quot;order[items][]\&quot; type=\&quot;checkbox\&quot; 
value=\&quot;7\&quot; /&gt;Burrito&lt;\/label&gt;&lt;
input name=\&quot;order[items][]\&quot; type=\&quot;hidden\&quot; 
value=\&quot;\&quot; /&gt;&lt;\/div&gt;&lt;\/div&gt;'

$('#items-list').html(info);
```

When It gets replaced, it has been turned into a string instead of a dom element. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you expect rails to caugh up an actual element? It's probably still going to be a string, you just need to get rid of the entities ?

Comment: Isn't that what the .html method should take care of?

Comment: Nope, that inserts HTML, and entities is used to make sure the content is inserted as text content, not HTML, so it's the opposite really.

Comment: Try this ... `$('#items-list').html($("<div/>").html(info).text());` http://jsfiddle.net/V6fJP/

Comment: So how can turn the entity into html dom elements?

Comment: @raina77ow Not really it is an encoded html string and so one way you can do it is by using a temp div. So just append is not enough, it is same as what OP is doing

Comment: A better approach would be to include the CGI library and use `unescapeHTML()` in Rails to convert the entities.

Comment: thanks, PSL's worked but Raina's did not... Not sure why

Comment: Of course, an even better approach would be not to entity encode the string to begin with ?

Comment: It's because append() and html() do the same thing, you have to get the string into the DOM with html() where the entities are converted by the browser, and then reappend the string you get from the DOM as HTML.